# How to check if a HUD is dismissed when using UI Automation

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I was trying to check a segmentControl.
When the segmentControl is tapped, a HUD (using [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD)) will show and block the UI.
I can't find a way to get the HUD so I can't check if a HUD is visable.
`target.delay(delay)` works but waste too muck time;

My code:

```
if (segmentControl.isValid()) {
    var length = segmentControl.buttons().length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var button = segmentControl.buttons()[i];
        this.target().pushTimeout(2);
        button.withValueForKey(1, "isVisible");
        this.target().popTimeout();
        button.tap();
    }
}
```

Log:

2013-10-10 09:33:50 +0000 Debug: target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().segmentedControls()[0].buttons()[0].tap()
2013-10-10 09:33:50 +0000 Debug: target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().segmentedControls()[0].buttons()[1].tap()
2013-10-10 09:33:50 +0000 Debug: target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().segmentedControls()[0].buttons()[2].tap()
2013-10-10 09:33:51 +0000 Debug: target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().segmentedControls()[0].buttons()[2] could not be tapped
2013-10-10 09:33:51 +0000 Error: target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().segmentedControls()[0].buttons()[2] could not be tapped

Thanks.